# Power Automate Flow folder 'NotFound.' when deleting

Tags: sharepoint, archive, power-automate

I am having issues with a flow I created used to archive folders on SharePoint.  The daily scheduled flow checks a folder has product and year metatag information and if it does it will copy the folder to a new directory depending on the year tagged and then delete the original folder.  If a folder already exists with the same name then the flow will cancel.

This flow has worked fine for months, then suddenly last week it is having issues completing the final part of the flow - to delete the folder.  There is no condition for this, it should just move on to the next step, however the error I am getting is ‘NotFound.’  What is making this more frustrating is it is still correctly checking, moving and deleting some of the folders.  I have attached screenshots below to try and show the flow’s structure and the error I am now receiving.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

This is the structure of the flow:

[image: Flow structure]

Here is the error I am receiving:

[image: Flow error deleting folder]

Here is the same flow with an identical folder being moved and deleted successfully:

[image: Successful flow deleting folder]

I have removed a lot of the 'Update file properties' box in the screenshots above just to keep the screenshot a reasonable size.